# How to aggregate an array of JSON objects with Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm looking to aggregate an array of JSON objects with Postgres, specifically for returning a list of relationships to another table by foreign key. In this case it's a `user` and their `teams`.

Here's the schema I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE memberships (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id TEXT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
  team_id TEXT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
);
```

With the following query:

```
  SELECT
    users.id,
    ...
    CASE
      WHEN count(teams.*) = 0
      THEN '[]'::JSON
      ELSE json_agg(DISTINCT teams.id)
    END AS teams
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN memberships ON users.id = memberships.user_id
  LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = memberships.team_id
  WHERE users.id = $[userId]
  GROUP BY
    users.id,
    ...
```

I can get results as a flat array of `team_id`s:

```
{
  id: 'user_1',
  ...
  teams: ['team_1', 'team_2']
}
```

But I'd like to receive the results as JSON objects instead:

```
{
  id: 'user_1',
  ...
  teams: [
    { id: 'team_1' },
    { id: 'team_2' }
  ]
}
```

I get extremely close with:

```
  SELECT
    users.id,
    ...
    CASE
      WHEN count(teams.*) = 0
      THEN '[]'::JSON
      ELSE json_agg(json_build_object('id', teams.id))
    END AS teams
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN memberships ON users.id = memberships.user_id
  LEFT JOIN teams ON teams.id = memberships.team_id
  WHERE users.id = $[userId]
  GROUP BY
    users.id,
    ...
```

But now I've lost the `DISTINCT` function's de-duping of results, so I end up with duplicate IDs returned for each `team`.

Comment: you need a subquery with array_to_json, see the last example here: https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this using a sub-query which selects the appropriate combinations, then aggregate into a `json` array:

```
SELECT id, json_strip_nulls(json_agg(json_build_object('id', team))) AS teams
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id AS id, team_id AS team
  FROM memberships
  WHERE user_id = $[userId]) sub
GROUP BY id;
```

You can get the user id from and the team id from the `memberships` table, so no point in joining either table to the `memberships` table (unless you get other fields from those tables that you haven't shown us). If you do want to use other fields you can paste the `JOIN`s right back in.

The `json_strip_nulls()` function will get rid of the `[{"id": null}]` occurrences and replace them with an empty `[]::json`. This is a PG 9.5 new feature. This also gets rid of the rather ugly and inefficient `CASE` clause.

Comment: Using `coalesce` seems to result in me getting `[{ id: null }]` returned when there are no matching teams still.

Comment: Sweet call on removing the need to join the extra tables, since `memberships` has the information I need too!

Comment: So you can have a user without a team. Fine. If a user has at least one membership, can he still have an entry without a team? As in `(user_id, team_id) = [(1, null), (1, 14), (1,26)]` or is that not possible?

Comment: If you use PG 9.5, see updated answer. (If not, upgrade. PG 9.5 `json` support is vastly expanded.)

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like this will do it:

```
SELECT  json_build_object(
          'id',    u.id,
          'teams', array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT t.*), NULL))
FROM    users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships m
ON      m.user_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN teams t
ON      m.team_id = t.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Works in 9.4. The part about removing `NULL`s is necessary for users with no team.

I suspect a good general principle when doing JSON in Postgres is to stick with arrays and records as long as possible, and only switch to JSON at the last moment. The more traditional structures have been around longer and are more closely tied to the relational model, so you're less likely to run into problems using them. You can see that this query could have just as easily returned a column named `id` and an array-valued column named `teams`.

Note this query gives all users. If you want just one, put that in a `WHERE` clause.